# MS Access: How can I get a 'Data type mismatch' when I'm using variants?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to open a report from a form in vba:

```
Dim ALS_ID As Variant
ALS_ID = Me.Controls("ALS_ID").Value
DoCmd.OpenReport "BoxLblRpt", acViewPreview, , "[ALS_ID]= '" & ALS_ID & "'"
```

but I'm getting:

```
Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

I'm using something of similar format that works without errors (PO_ID and Part are also both variants):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "OutgoingBoxLblRpt", acNormal, , "[PO_ID]= '" & PO_ID & "' AND [PART] = '" & PartCombo & "'"
```

How can I get a type mismatch in the first OpenReport if I'm using a variant?

Comment: At a guess `ALS_ID` is a numeric field and by adding the enclosing single quotes you're passing it as a string.  Try removing the quotes. `DoCmd.OpenReport "BoxLblRpt", acViewPreview, , "[ALS_ID]= " & ALS_ID`

Comment: That was exactly it. I'm still new to VBA so I wasn't aware that's what the quotes did. If you create a response I'll accept it.

Comment: `Variant` means the variable can receive any type. Doesn't mean the value it contains can magically be converted into a string without problems. Did you put a breakpoint on the error line to inspect the value of `ALS_ID`? FWIW your variables should be `String`, you're implicitly converting them to strings anyway,

Comment: No, I didn't know you could. I've always used message boxes, but I'll be using breakpoints from now on.